# JSF Flash - Unexpected behavior - Values of the Flash remains alive

Tags: jsf, tomcat

i'm having an unexpected behavior while using the ELflash of JSF.
I have two pages(page1 and page2) each page have his own managedVean(Bean1 and Bean2).
In page1, i have a button thah calls this method from Bean1:

```
ELFlash.getFlash().put("xxx", "Test");
    return "page2?faces-redirect=true";
```

and in the page2, i have the following statement in the constructor, to recover the value from the flash:

```
Map<String,Object> flash = ELFlash.getFlash();
    for(String s : flash.keySet()){
        if(s.equals("xxx")){
            myVariable=true;
        }
    }
```

And when i click the button in the page1 it redirects to page2 and sets the variable myVariable to true.
The problem is, after that if i update the page, or even re-open the page in another tab, it keeps entering in the if statement setting the myVariable to true.
if i look at the console, i see a warning from tomcat:

*03/05/2013 08:57:56 com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash setCookie
AVISO: JSF1095: The response was already committed by the time we tried to set the outgoing cookie for the flash.  Any values stored to the flash will not be available on the next request.*

By what i understand, te flash should clean it's state after the request is over.
Or i must clean it manually?